# Receiving a form from a php page

Tags: vb.net

I have a scenario that I am stuck with for a day now. There is this PHP website that I am trying to extract some data from. So I go to the website and there is this form that I can fill and when I click "submit" it takes me to another page where it has a table with all the information that I want.

I took that link and tried to parse the HTML but there was no table. And I checked that link from another computer and it was not loading up the table.

So I'm not sure what I should do here in order to get to that table? Do I have to do some sort of http request of some sort? If so How can it be done in vb.net ?

cheers

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're having some basic difficulty with this. Depending on your browser try right clicking the 'table' page and 'View Source'. Save the HTML to a local file and open it using Visual Studio, Notepad++, or any other HTML editor.

Whta looks like a table when displayed in the browser may be encoded as a table, a div, or even a list with some clever formatting. Parsing each of those is a diferent task. without seeing the page I think that nobody will be able to help you much further.